# Integrate a class extending HttpServlet in a project using javax.ws.rs notations

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I have been given the task to implement my service in the service layer made by another developer, but I can't find the right way to do it.
Initially my class worked independently on a Tomcat server, here is a snip:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class fileServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Override
   public void doGet(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
       OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
       String  queryString = request.getQueryString();
//etcetera....
```

Here a snip of the classes made by the other person:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/CustomerService")
public class SolrService {

@GET
@Path("/customers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Map<String,Object>> getCustomers(@QueryParam("mode") String mode,@QueryParam("query") String query,@QueryParam("fields") String fields){
    return get(mode,query,fields);
}
```

I am fairly new to the servlet environment and to java web development too, so looking for an easy way to do this I

- imported javax.ws.rs and put the notations in my class, like so:

  ```
  @Path("/FileManager")
   public class fileServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @GET
  @Path("/fileGetter")
  @Override
  public void doGet(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response)


             throws IOException, ServletException {
     OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
     String  queryString = request.getQueryString();
  ```
- compiled and put the .class file in the folder specified in the web.info in TomCat, plus added the servlet.jar in the lib. The web.info

  ```
     <servlet>
     <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>company.rest</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  ```

  ```
     <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  ```

  but I can't reach my service following the address. 
  I'm reading lots of answers, but can't get it working anyway. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like I made it. So the tags were a right step ahead:

```
@Path("/FileManager")
public class fileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @GET
    @Path("/fileGetter/{fileString}")
   public void doGet(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response,@PathParam("fileString") String fileName)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
       OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
       //Get the fileID.png
       String fileString = fileName;
```

Note that the method is still a doGet, but it cannot `@Override` the HttpServlet method, as it takes a new parameter. It still works, though, thanks to the `@GET` tag.
The real trick was adding my class in the loading of the web.xml:

```
    <init-param>

  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>

  <param-value>gft.rest.FileServlet</param-value>

</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Between the `<servlet>`